# how to resort a array by key 'date'？

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to sort a multidemensional array by an inner key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545544/how-to-sort-a-multidemensional-array-by-an-inner-key)
>   [How to sort a multidimensional array by a certain key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804690/how-to-sort-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-certain-key)

I want my array to be sort by date asc, how to do?

```
<?php
    //how to resort a array by key 'date'？
    $arr=array(
        array(
            'name'=>'a',
            'date'=>'2012-10-21 18:00:00'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'x',
            'date'=>'2013-10-21 18:00:00'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'d',
            'date'=>'2011-10-21 18:00:00'
        )
    );
?>
```

Comment: order by in sql if it is possible then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function sort_by_date($a, $b) {
  return( $a['date'] < $b['date'] ? -1 : ($a['date'] > $b['date']) ? 1 : 0 );
}

usort($arr, 'sort_by_date');
```