# Multisorting a nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've got a bunch of content pulled out of several databases and compiled into a nested array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [published] => 1433940002
            [content] => This is some content
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [published] => 1433940001
            [content] => This is some more content
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [published] => 1433940003
            [content] => This is some more content
        )
)
```

Since I cannot sort the content whilst it is retrieved (because it is done using several queries from as many databases) I want to dig down a level into the array and sort by the "published" date whilst maintaining the depth of the array so I end up with...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 52
            [published] => 1433940001
            [content] => This is some more content
        )
     [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [published] => 1433940002
            [content] => This is some content
        )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [published] => 1433940003
            [content] => This is some more content
        )
)
```

I'm pretty sure array_multisort() is the way to go but I can't think where to start! Could somebody be so kind as to give me a pointer?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2545544/3933332

Comment: Thanks, @Rizier123 - that was enough to push me in the right direction!

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy your day :)

Comment: It's 11 o'clock at night here! My brain is beginning to shut down ;) I'll try to enjoy tomorrow though!

Comment: Same for me. *But wait!* You still have 1 minute left to enjoy the day :) (Nah to late now, now you can enjoy the next 24 hours)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Rizier123's policing of my question I figured it out myself. For anyone else finding this thread here's my solution using the example array I supplied above.

```
//-- get disorganised content from databases here

usort($array, "publishcmp");

//-- output organised content here

function publishcmp($a , $b){
    if ($a['published'] == $b['published']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['published'] < $b['published']) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Pretty much taken verbatim from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)